# Mount NTFS device in C++ on linux?

Tags: c++, linux, mount

I'm attempting to mount an external drive in my C++ application. I originally tried to use mount(2) but this fails:

```
int ret = mount(deviceName.c_str(), mountPoint.c_str(), fsType.c_str(), 0, NULL);
```

errno is 19, `ENODEV` (filesystem type not configured in kernel)

However, if I switch to using mount(8) it works fine:

```
std::string cmd = "mount -t " + fsType + " " + deviceName + " " + mountPoint;
int ret = system(cmd.c_str());
```

Does mount(2) have a different list of acceptable filesystem types? This is an ntfs device, so I was using `ntfs-3g` as the fstype. I checked /proc/filesystems and saw that this was not listed, so I tried `fuseblk` but that just changes the error to 22, `EINVAL`.

What is the correct way to mount NTFS devices using mount(2)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`mount.2` is just a kernel call. `mount.8` is a complete external tool which is extended beyond what kernel does.

I think you may be looking for [libmount](http://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/utils/util-linux/v2.22/libmount-docs/) which is a library implementing the whole mounting magic done by `mount.8`. Newer mount versions use it as well. It's provided in [util-linux](http://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/utils/util-linux/).

Comment: Ah, I admit I had assumed that under the hood mount.2 would be calling mount.8. That explains why they were not functioning the same way. Thank for pointing me towards `libmount`, I will check it out.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried running `mount(8)` using the `strace` command? It will print out the system calls made by the program, including `mount(2)`. When I do such a mount, it spawns `mount.ntfs` (which is NTFS-3g) which then does a `mount` for `fuseblk` and then spins off into the background to support that mount point.

FUSE-based filesystems are handled differently because the user-space daemon must be started. Mounting with `fuseblk` doesn't provide enough information for the kernel to start the daemon (and the kernel doesn't even really have the information to start the daemon). For ntfs-3g, one would normally do something like `ntfs-3g /dev/sda1 /mnt/windows` (from the help). There isn't a programmatic way to tell the kernel to do this because it happens in user-space.